# Is ros2 service echo command exist?

Tags: ros2

https://docs.ros.org/en/iron/Tutorials/Beginner-CLI-Tools/Understanding-ROS2-Services/Understanding-ROS2-Services.html#ros2-service-echo

In this part, I found that ros2 service echo had been explained and exists.
But when I use "ros2 service -h" command there are only 4 commands available.

call, find, list, and type.

So, update ros2-iron

By,
sudo apt update/
sudo apt upgrade/
sudo apt-get update/
sudo apt-get upgrade

But still same, so I installed ros2-iron again.
But the result was same.

I found that the 8. ros2 service echo part was updated only 3 days ago.

https://github.com/ros2/ros2_documentation/commits/iron/source/Tutorials/Beginner-CLI-Tools/Understanding-ROS2-Services/Understanding-ROS2-Services.rst

And also there is no chapter 7.
And didn't exist in other versions of ros2. (Humble, Foxy, etc.)

But there is no reason, the developers updated the wrong or non-existent command.
So, is there anyone who knows about this?

Comment: And I also followed the tutorials of the chapter 8.
But didn't work. ㅠㅠ

Comment: I have also tried the tutorial and still does not work. I mean they have pushed and merged recently. Maybe is still not functional on master....

Comment: Thx for trying!
It would be awesome if the echo function worked with the service command.
Then the only thing we can do is wait! 

Comment: but other functionalities of ros2 service is not useful for you get info? I mean in your node you could add print statements to see what is going on...not so trivial but is a partial solution

Comment: Thx for your comments. I mean that it would be useful to use the echo function with the service command. So, we can use it like as "ros2 topic echo". Then we will observe real-time communication between the service clients, and server with just a command!
Isn't it amazing!?

Comment: Totally agree! If you write in their GitHub commit of this feature that is still now working...maybe they can take a look at it and enable it. What do you think? I can comment too as well if you track this commit.

Comment: It might make more sense to raise a github issue, if there is a problem with the tutorial.

Comment: @MarcusVinicius - `still now working` or *still **not** working*? Presumably the latter.

Comment: I have not checked yet if is working or not.